# Получить тело запроса на стороне сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, post, yandex-cloud

Клиент отправляет POST-запрос:

```
  const array = [1, 2, 3];

  fetch("https://...yandexcloud.net/save-questions", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(array)
  });
```

На стороне сервера вызывается функция:

```
module.exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(event.body));
```

Результат: "WzEsMiwzXQ=="

Что надо еще указать, чтобы можно было на стороне сервера получить нужный мне объект в расшифрованном виде?
Сервер находится в Yandex Cloud. Может в облаке нужно еще что-то настроить.
Спасибо.

Comment: `WzEsMiwzXQ==` == `[1,2,3]` кодировка **base64**

Comment: @Jour а откуда этот base64 тут в принципе взялся вообще?

Comment: Ну, вот и мне интересно. Если я правильно понимаю, то в вакууме запросы не шифруются. Значит это на стороне yandex cloud

Comment: @andreymal  вообще без понятия откуда) нужно читать документацию яндекс)

Comment: Если я верно всё вижу, то код крутится внутри функции. Так что, вот вам документация https://cloud.yandex.ru/ru/docs/functions/concepts/function-invoke#request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге сделал так:

```
     const valueString =
        Buffer
            .from(JSON.stringify(event.body), 'base64')
            .toString("utf8");

    const myObjects = JSON.parse(valueString) as MyObject[];
```

Answer (score 0):

*Намёк на то, что можно закрыть вопрос, т.к. Вы нашли решение.*

В общем-то, я подтверждаю Вам, что решение Вы нашли => закрытие вопроса (или фарм голосов?):

`Buffer.from(data, 'base64')`

Вместо `'base64'` может быть `hex`, `utf8` и прочие (см. вторую ссылку)

Подробнее **о методе**:
https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding

Подробнее **о вариантах (де)кодирования**:
https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-buffer.php

`.toString()` также поддерживает эти варианты.

Примеры, где это также может быть полезно: `Buffer`<-`'binary'` (де-факто):

- `require('node:crypto').createHash(/*к примеру*/'md5').update(data, 'hex')`
- `require('node:fs').readFileSync(data, 'utf8')`

Comment: У меня не хватило "репутации", чтобы написать комментарий под Ваш ответ, автор вопроса.

Comment: Я, если честно, не совсем в контексте того, как на сайте заведено с закрытием вопросов, поэтому про фарм голосов даже не понимаю. Попробую нажать закрыть